# AngularJS Directive Run Callback With Params

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've got a pretty simple directive that I'd like to be able to run a callback with parameters supplied by the directive and the scope. For example:

```
<div ng-repeat="user in users">
  <div sample="..." callback="welcome(user, $message)">
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm having trouble using [$parse](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$parse) to handle this. My sample directive is as follows:

```
app.directive('sample', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {},
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      // ...
      function greet () {
        var callback = $parse(attrs.callback);
        callback(scope, { $message: 'Howdy' });
      }
    },
  },
}]);
```

However, despite getting a function from $parse - executing the function never results in my welcome function (defined in a controller) being called (note: on Angular 1.5.x). I'm assuming scope is wrong somehow (that it is using the isolated scope instead of the parent scope) - but I do need an isolated scope (simplified for example). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you need `$parse` and a directive in general? If this is for one controller, you could define `$scope.greet` in the controller.

Comment: The directive is used for multiple controllers and the 'callback' has different parameters (and optional '$message') in the definition for them (so not possible).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you use `scope.$parent` as a parameter to your `$parse` call? You may also wish to wrap with a `$scope.$apply(function () { ... });`.

Comment: I don't think isolate scopes have access to any parent

Comment: @phil An isolated scope's $parent always refs a parent scope. Isolated means it doesn't inherit prototypically from a parent scope - *NOT* that $parent isn't defined.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the [`&` isolate scope binding](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-scope-). I'd also provide the `user` object to your directive

```
return {
  restrict: 'A',
  scope: {
    user: '<',
    callback: '&'
  }
  link: function(scope) {
    // ...
    function greet() {
      scope.callback({
        user: scope.user,
        $message: 'Howdy'
      })
    }
  }
}
```

and

```
<div sample="..." user="user" callback="welcome(user, $message)">
```

Comment: This solution adds pretty strong coupling between the user and the directive (I'm trying to avoid and make the directive as generic as possible). I'm aiming for a directive much closer to the likes of `ng-click` - where the directive fills in some key parameters - but otherwise doesn't need to know about the outside happenings. I ideally need to support things like:

`callback="welcome()"` and `callback="welcome(user)"` and `callback="welcome(item, $message)"` and `callback="welcome(item, user, $message)"`.

Comment: @Stussa it's not tight coupling, it simply becomes part of the directive's API. In any case, I'm glad you found a solution that works for you